# Connection Timeout on Pub/sub push based subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

While working with huge on Pub/sub topic where push-based subscription is calling cloud run (running spring boot server with jetty), we have noticed very strange behavior.

So when the push based subscription calls the cloud run, and if cloud run experiences some cold start or has delay with spring boot loading itself, it feels like that push subscription does a connection timeout thinking connection was not established/connection was bad, but the (stuck) request somehow still continue with its execution once the container eventually starts.

So at the end, we are getting some duplicate processing (one from the original call which was eventually processed by cloud run but was seen as connection timeout from subscription side, and second being the retry from subscription)

Wanted to know if there is any connection timeout on push subscription and how much it is?

Comment: Looking here https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/create ...and looking at the "ackDeadlineSeconds" attribute ... we read "For push delivery, this value is also used to set the request timeout for the call to the push endpoint.".   It appears to be a default value of 10 seconds.

Comment: If you read it, it talks about the time subscriber gets to process and acknowledge before it gets retried from subscription, and i am here not talking out that, I am well aware about that setting. I am more interested in connection related timeouts

Comment: If the ack deadline is 10 seconds ... I would imagine that when GCP PubSub forms an HTTP request to push a subscription message then if it doesn't receive a response in the ack deadline period then it would cancel (timeout) the connection.  In the docs, where it says "For push delivery, this value is also used to set the request timeout for the call to the push endpoint." ... is a request timeout not also the notion of a connection related timeout?   Maybe increase the ackDeadlineSeconds and see if that changes what you experience.

Comment: We did try to increase the  ack deadline and play around with those settings to see if it changed anything for us, it did not.

Comment: If it were me, I'd likely do some technical tests now.  I'd create a REST endpoint that I control and configured a PUSH subscription to push to it.  I'd then publish a message to the topic and see what happens when I fail to ack over periods of time.  What if I ACK imemdiately, what if I ACK at 10 seconds, at 30 seconds and at 60 seconds (assuming an ack deadline of 10 seconds).  I'd see if that changes (materially) what you are seeing from Spring Boot.

Comment: Tried it, but weird thing is, we get this glitches when we have a peak of high load, ãround10k undelivered message, and we get like 100 duplicates. was not able to replicate this behavior with smaller load

Comment: If I read this correctly,  https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/handling-duplicate-data-in-streaming-pipeline-using-pubsub-dataflow ... it seems that out of the box PubSub assures "at least once delivery" as opposed to "once and once only delivery".  What that seems to say to me is that the onus is on the subscriber to recognize and handle an attempt to process the same message being delivered twice.

Comment: Hello Juhi@. Is your issue resolved?